# Detect (and remove) scratches from a set of pictures

Tags: image, opencv, computer-vision

To simplify, I have a set of pictures shot from a camera. This camera was behind an acrylic dome and this dome has scratches on it. The scratches are very apparent in the pictures. 
With opencv, I'm trying to detect and remove these scratches. 
My first approach is to multiply a subset of the pictures to create a mask, than apply the inpaint mask. Am I on the right track? Is there a treatment I can do on the images before multiplying them?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

EDIT:
Here is an image highlighting the scratches [image]

Comment: Could you provide a few example images?

Comment: A median filter can be effective on thin scratches.

Comment: can you please mark the noise/ Scratches that you want to remove in a separate image?

Comment: what is Scratch in your image? it is unclear! Can you point it?

Comment: @BalajiR: I think [this](https://i.imgur.com/CI9dmqk.jpg) is one of the bigger scratches OP is taling about. It's present in all 4 of his images.

Comment: @BalajiR I provided an example of some of the scratches. They are repeated on each picture.

Comment: Does your camera unmountable and the number of scratches are constant? I think you should "calibrate" your camera by capturing some frames from a homogeneous surface (i.e. a white or black paper). It's much easier to detect scratches on a frame as mentioned before as on a tube image.

Comment: I agree with Kornel, if possible put a white paper behind the glass top, then it is much easier to detect location of the scratches and you can remove them using inpainting techniques.

Comment: @Kornel, The number of scratches are constant within a set of picture taken on the same location, but some scratches may be added each day with the manipulation of the camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few tests, I came with a reliable way to eliminate recurring scratches and dust spots on a set of images. First, I take a subset of 10 to 15 pictures, open them, and apply [sobel derivatives](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/sobel_derivatives/sobel_derivatives.html) to extract the contours.

```
        private Image<Gray, byte> GetImageContours(String strImage)
        {
            Image<Gray, Byte> img = new Image<Gray, byte>(strImage);
            Image<Gray, float> gradx = img.Sobel(1, 0, 5);
            Image<Gray, Byte> gradxconv = gradx.ConvertScale<Byte>(1, 0);
            Image<Gray, float> grady = img.Sobel(0, 1, 5);
            Image<Gray, Byte> gradyconv = grady.ConvertScale<Byte>(1, 0);
            Image<Gray, Byte> imgContours = gradxconv.AddWeighted(gradyconv, 0.5, 0.5, 0);

            img.Dispose();
            gradx.Dispose();
            grady.Dispose();
            gradxconv.Dispose();
            gradyconv.Dispose();

            return imgContours;
        }
```

Then, I convert the images back to a 16bit depth, then multiply all of them. This should give me an image of the scratches only.
To create a mask of the scratches, I erode this image one time, then dilate it 10 times. After that, I convert it to black and white by running a TresholdBinary with a treshold value of 40.

The final step is to use the Inpaint function on all the set of images with the scratch mask.

```
            Image<Gray, float> _img1 = img1.Convert<Gray, float>();
            Image<Gray, float> _img2 = img2.Convert<Gray, float>();
            Image<Gray, float> _img3 = img3.Convert<Gray, float>();
            Image<Gray, float> _img4 = img4.Convert<Gray, float>();
            Image<Gray, float> _img5 = img5.Convert<Gray, float>();
            Image<Gray, float> _img6 = img6.Convert<Gray, float>();
            Image<Gray, float> _img7 = img7.Convert<Gray, float>();
            Image<Gray, float> _img8 = img8.Convert<Gray, float>();
            Image<Gray, float> _img9 = img9.Convert<Gray, float>();
            Image<Gray, float> _img10 = img10.Convert<Gray, float>();
            Image<Gray, float> _img11 = img11.Convert<Gray, float>();
            Image<Gray, float> _img12 = img12.Convert<Gray, float>();
            Image<Gray, float> imgMask = _img1.Mul(_img2).Mul(_img3).Mul(_img4).Mul(_img5).Mul(_img6).Mul(_img7).Mul(_img8).Mul(_img9).Mul(_img10).Mul(_img11).Mul(_img12).Erode(1);
            Image<Gray, Byte> imgMask2 = imgMask.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
            Image<Gray, Byte> imgMask3 = imgMask2.Dilate(10).ThresholdBinary(new Gray(40), new Gray(255));

            //img is one of the original images to remove scratches on
            ImageViewer viewer3 = new ImageViewer(img.InPaint(imgMask3, 3), "image3");
            viewer3.Show();
```

Here are sample images taken at each step:

original image 
[image]

contours of this image
[image]

all the contours multiplied
[image]

the mask eroded and dilated
[image]

the final result
[image]